# Proper way to cache jQuery objects when writing a plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

I wrote a plugin and I cache the elements that the plugin applies to in `$.data("myPlugIn",[])`. Is this a good way to do it ?

Also is it ok to do this `$.data("myPlugIn").globalVar`  or absolutely bad ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache jQuery objects for persistent states, then it's ok to store them in data. I can hardly see a use case where you would want to cache the jQuery objects for persistent states, but your case might be different.

However, if you are caching jQuery objects for execution state in data, then you are doing it wrong.

Either way, I believe the speed of read and write to data is much more slower, so I think it's better for you to build the jQuery objects again, rather than read them from data.